# How to get and set JSON data with Webtask storage?

Tags: javascript, json, webtask

Trying to figure out how to save mouse coordinates to Webtask storage after reading this post:
https://blog.codepen.io/2018/05/04/say-you-need-to-get-set-some-json-data-from-a-pen/

I want to create a heatmap that will write mouse coordinates to Webtask storage when user clicks inside a div. And loads the updated data on page load.

### This is what I got so far

```js
const webtask_url = `https://wt-944eb9b4c90e6c80852f9671db4a1404-0.sandbox.auth0-extend.com/heatmap`;

var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var style = getComputedStyle(document.body);

canvas.width = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('--s'), 10); 
canvas.height = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('--s'), 10); 

//fill canvas
ctx.fillStyle = style.getPropertyValue('--c1');
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var mouse = {
  x: undefined,
  y: undefined
}

//get mouse position inside the div
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), // abs. size of element
      scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width,    // relationship bitmap vs. element for X
      scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;  // relationship bitmap vs. element for Y

  return {
    x: (evt.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX,   // scale mouse coordinates after they have
    y: (evt.clientY - rect.top) * scaleY     // been adjusted to be relative to element
  }
}

//click event
window.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  mouse.x = getMousePos(canvas, event).x;
  mouse.y = getMousePos(canvas, event).y;
  drawPoint(mouse.x, mouse.y);

  let data = {
    "x": mouse.x,
    "y": mouse.y
  };
  
//trying to send the coordinates to Webtask
  fetch(webtask_url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log('data is', data))

});

//draw a circle
function drawPoint(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.shadowBlur=10;
  ctx.shadowColor="rgb(233, 30, 99)";
  ctx.arc(x,y,5,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = style.getPropertyValue('--c2');
  ctx.fill();
}

//load coordinates from Webtask storage
fetch(webtask_url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
  data.forEach(function(item, i) {
    drawPoint(item.x, item.y);
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --bg: whitesmoke; 
  --c1: #5E35B1;
  --c2: #E91E63;
  --s: 300px;
  --shadow: 0 1em 5em -1em rgba(94, 53, 177, 0.8);
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
}

body {
  background: var(--bg);
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  display: grid;
}

#canvas {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

### **Webtask side**

Author is updating color field in the Storage. My problem is that I am completely lost here. I understand I have to adjust ctx.storage.set part to accept my coordinates but I don't want to update them, I want to create a new entry in my JSON.

```
module.exports = function(ctx, cb) {

 if (Object.keys(ctx.query).length !== 0) {
   ctx.storage.set(ctx.query, { force: 1 }, function (error) {
      if (error) return cb(error);
      cb(null, { 
        "message": "success" ,
        "color": ctx.query.color
      });
   });
 } else {
   ctx.storage.get(function (error, data) {
      if (error) return cb(error);
      cb(null, data);
   });
 }

}
```

Comment: Maybe there is a simpler alternative to using Webtask? In the end I just need to store and edit a JSON file.

Comment: When you say, "create a new entry", do you mean like add to the end of an array?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *append* values to a list you'll need to store and manipulate an array instead of an object.

With ES6 the easiest way to do so is with the spread operator:

```
newData = [...oldData, newItem]
```

I've refactored your code a bit.

```
module.exports = (ctx, cb) => {
  ctx.storage.get((error, data) => {
    if (error) return cb(error)
    if (Object.keys(ctx.query).length === 0) {
      cb(null, data)
    } else {
      const newData = [...data, ctx.query]
      ctx.storage.set(newData, error => {
        if (error) return cb(error)
        cb(null, { "message": "success" , "color": ctx.query.color })
      })
    }
  })
}
```